# Firebird insert hex values into tables (arithmetic exception)

Tags: python, sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm having a problem when I try to insert values into a firebird database. I'm inserting values into the table using hex representations.

I'm doing an insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO ACCELEROMETER (PHYSICALID, XACCEL, YACCEL, ZACCEL, TIMEEPOCH,
    TIMEOFFSET, TSTAMP)
VALUES (2, 0x12DF,  0x8000, 0x12, 0x45612, 0x0, current_timestamp);
```

The problem occurs when I try to insert a value that is bigger than 0x7FFF. I know that all firebird variables are signed so whenever I try to insert a value like 0x8000 I'm supposed to get a value -32768, but I keep getting this message:

> Engine Code    : 335544321 Engine Message :
>
> arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation numeric
>   value is out of range

It looks like when I try to insert 0x8000 firebird thinks it is 32768, which would obviously not work because it is bigger than what it is allowed for SMALLINT fields. I was under the impression that if I inserted hex values firebird would see that the most significant bit was set and it would know that this is a negative value. Am I missing something here ??

Thanks,

Here is the table:

```
RECREATE TABLE accelerometer ( 
  id int not null primary key,
  physicalId int not null, -- foreign key physicalDevice table
  xAccel SMALLINT,
  yAccel SMALLINT,
  zAccel SMALLINT,
  timeEpoch BIGINT,
  timeOffset INTEGER,
  tStamp timeStamp -- time stamp generated by the firebird db at the time a record is entered
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird will see the sign bit but not for *SMAILLINT*. In range **0 .. 7FFFFFF** it will be positive and in range **80000000 .. FFFFFFFF** it will be negative. The values in the range will be *INTEGER*. You can prepend zeroes to force the value to be *BIGINT*. But there is no clue that it will behave the same for *SMAILLINT*. So the value **0x8000** should be **32768** and beyond the boundary of *SMALLINT*. You may refer [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-hexnumerals.html).